# Evil text objects on kebab-case behave differently on dw and cw

Tags: spacemacs, evil, syntax-table

I would like my evil text objects to work on kebab-case words, so that `dw` or `cw` act on the "whole-kebab-word" and not just on "whole".

Therefor I have put `(modify-syntax-entry ?- "w" clojure-mode-syntax-table)` into the `clojure-mode-hook` in my `.spacemacs`.

Now `dw` works on the whole kebab-word, but `cw` does not. It changes only the first part. Why is that?